A Steiner tree-like problem where cycles are allowed
I recently wanted to model a vehicle routing problem and encountered this one:
Suppose we have an unweighted connected graph $G=(V,E)$, where some nodes, say $V^{'}\subseteq V$ have prizes. The prize for node $v^{'}_i$ is $p_i$. Also, traversing each edge has a penalty of $\epsilon$. If a traveler starts at a random node, how can he maximize his reward?
I am wondering if this is a well-known problem, or at least a well-known np-complete problem can be reduced to it. When $\epsilon$ is 0, it is somehow similar to Steiner tree, although in this problem cycles are allowed. It also somehow resembles TSP, but here nodes can be visited more than once.
I am wondering if this problem is NP-Hard or not. If so, which problem can be reduced to it?

You don't state it directly and unambiguously, but I suppose that you want to maximize
$$\sum_{i \in I} p_i - \epsilon \sum_{e \in E} f(e),$$
where $\{\,v'_i\quad\forall i \in I\,\} \subseteq V'$ is subset of visited vertices with prizes and $f(e)$ is the number of times the edge $e$ is traversed. Then putting $V' = V$, $p_i = 1$ for all $i$ and $\epsilon = \frac 1{n - 1}$ we get that the maximum rewards is $n - 1$ if and only if there exists a Hamiltonian path with one end in the starting vertex, since for visiting every new vertex at least one edge should be traversed. (If the traveler has to return to the starting vertex, then for $\epsilon = \frac 1n$ the maximum reward is $n - 1$ is and only if there exists a Hamitonian cycle.) Thus your problem is $\mathrm{NP}$-hard.
